# Laravel dynamic databse change passport return unautorize 401 over api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-passport

I am sending dynamic db name over request header and using middleware i am changing db name.
but after login other request return unautorize. please help me to solve this. thanks in advance.
my middleware is

```
\Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', request()->header('db_name'));
 DB::purge('mysql');
```

and my axios header is

```
const apiCall = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_API_URL,
    timeout: 100000,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer' + useJwt.getToken,
        'db_name': VueCookie.get('db_name'),
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i call this middleware from kernel on $middlewareGroups so thats not working after call this middleware on global middleware it working well.